# Ruby/Rails 3: Turning a set of object attributes into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
@video = Video.find(params[:id])

@lengths = @video.each do |i|
  @length = i.length * 60
end
```

Firstly, I presumed @video would have an each, but instead got this error:

```
undefined method `each' for #<Video:0x4738428>
```

Secondly, is there any Ruby one-liner magic that could substitute for the last 3 lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@video is not an array in this case, it is an object because you asked the Video model to return only one video, the one with the id given in the params array.

In case you want to retrieve all videos from the database, do this:

```
@video = Video.all
```

Now @video will be an array of video objects.

Comment: Also, if you just want a single Video object but as an array, just do this: `@videos = [Video.find(params[:id])]`

Answer (score 1):

Pizzicato answered your question just fine, but here's my two cents:

If you would like to know the class of an object, you can do:

p Video.find(params[:id]).class